# Does Linux Pipe command needs a process to execute?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, linux-kernel

```
ls -la | sort | less
```

In the above command, how many linux processes run?

Is it 3 (one for `ls -la`, one for `sort`, one for `less`)?

Or is it 5 (one for `ls -la`, one for `sort`, one for `less`, one each for each pipe)?

Does `|` commands need a separate process to run?

Answer (score 1):

3 processes. The parent process, or the process where you're calling this command from (your command line), calls `pipe(2)` once for each two processes that get piped together so `ls -la | sort | less` needs to call `pipe(2)` twice to create two pipes: one for piping `ls` to `sort`, and one to pipe `sort` to `less`. Bash then forks itself once for each process (in this case 3 times). Before the children run their commands, they overwrite stdin and/or stdout. An example flow of the command would be:

1. Bash creates 2 pipes, one from `ls` to `sort`, and one from `sort` to `less`
2. Bash forks itself 3 times
3. Child 1 (`ls`) sets its stdout fd to write to pipe A
4. Child 2 (`sort`) sets its stdin fd to read from pipe A
5. Child 2 (`sort`) sets its stdout fd to write to pipe B
6. Child 3 (`less`) sets its stdin fd to read from pipe B
7. Each child runs its command

The pipes are used to direct stdin and/or stdout of the child processes, but the pipes themselves are not processes.

Comment: That's actually a total of four processes, not three, no? The parent and three kids.

Comment: @rici sure, but the fourth process is just the shell that you're running the command from (aka the "parent" process)

Answer (score 0):

A pipe in a shell is, in general, a call to [`pipe(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe), two calls to [`dup2(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2), and invocation of the two commands. The pipe itself does not require a separate process since the kernel is responsible for channeling data from one process to the next.